# Error while opening Windows Registry or Command Prompt as administrator after registry edit

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-registry, regedit

I am using Windows 10.

I have made some changes in Windows Registry.

Actually I have changed paths in keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0
```

Of course before I have exported registry to file. But this occurs to be broken somehow. So I typed back the paths I have changed (I think I have not maked mistake, but never could be sure).

I have closed regedit then. Then Visual studio stopped to be working and I couldn't open new one.

Moreover I can't open registry again ! I am getting error message dialog with path of the registry backup and information "The extended attributes are incosistent".

Moreover I can't open CommandPrompt as Administrator, because I am getting another error message dialog with information: "this file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. please install a program or if one is already installed created command prompt as administrator".

How I can make my environment stable again ?
Can I restore somehow kind of background copy of my regedit if something like this is done ?
How I can open registry or command prompt as administrator in that case ?

I tried also to open cmd normally and then type runas in order to open regedit or cmd as an administrator but the password or name are incorrect...

Comment: How does your backup appear to be broken? Did you export the ENTIRE registry, or just the portions you were going to modify? Even if the files will not re-import into the registry, you should still be able to open them in Notepad and find the specific values you are having to guess at.

Comment: Further, why were you editing the registry? What were you trying to accomplish? Were you following a particular guide?